# (discord.py) Why am I getting the error "command is not found"?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

## **THIS QUESTION HAS BEEN SOLVED BY FURAS IN THE COMMENTS.**

So I was following [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/jHZlvRr9KxM) on how to create a discord music bot like Rythm using discord.py. I had troubleshooted my code and fixed a few errors to do with coroutine.

EDIT: I have called the r function and now get this error upon running the code:

> main.py:15: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'r' was never awaited
> r()

When I run the code everything boots up successfully until I try to use a command. If I put '@join' in the chat it should have joined the voice chat or said "You're not in a voice channel!". Instead I get this error:

> 2022-09-02 20:07:08 ERROR    discord.ext.commands.bot Ignoring exception in command None
> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "join" is not found

I have tried swapping out @commands.command for @client.command (whilst also defining client in music.py) but more of the same. Any help would be much appreciated.

I have two files, main.py and music.py.

**MAIN.PY**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import music

cogs = [music]

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='@', intents=discord.Intents.all())


async def r():
    for i in range(len(cogs)):
        await cogs[i].setup(client)

r()

client.run(
    "my token")
```

**MUSIC.PY**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl


class music(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def join(self, ctx):
        if ctx.author.voice is None:
            await ctx.send("You're not in a voice channel!")
        voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        if ctx.voice_client is None:
            await voice_channel.connect()
        else:
            await ctx.voice_client.move_to(voice_channel)

    @commands.command()
    async def disconnect(self, ctx):
        await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()

    @commands.command()
    async def play(self, ctx, url):
        ctx.voice_client.stop()
        FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 - 
        reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
        YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': "bestaudio"}
        vc = ctx.voice_client

        with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
            info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
            url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
            source = await discord.FFmpegOpusAudio.from_probe(
                url2, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
            vc.play(source)

    @commands.command()
    async def pause(self, ctx):
        await ctx.voice_client.pause()
        await ctx.send("Paused")

    @commands.command()
    async def resume(self, ctx):
        await ctx.voice_client.resume()
        await ctx.send("Resumed")


async def setup(client):
    await client.add_cog(music(client))
```

Comment: I've made a discord bot in python a while ago-- I believe it may have to do with the aliases you give your function. Not sure if this will do anything but you could try `@commands.command(aliases=["join"])` above the decorator for your join function in music.py

Comment: @Mitchnoff no that didn't work - still the same error. Thanks anyway though.

Comment: Seems like you never run the `r` function?

Comment: @decorator-factory that completely slipped my mind. However, when I try to run it I get the error `main.py:15: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'r' was never awaited
  r()`

should I import asyncio and use asyncio.run()?

Comment: @lad12345 its worth a shot! If the `setup()` function you call is not asynchronous then you can put it in a normal function I believe and then call it. If it is async then you will need it in an async function.

Comment: as I rember it needs `async def setup(client):...` (and this should be in documentation) and it has to run `await client.add_cog(...)` (and this `await`  is missed in documentation)

Comment: @furas thank you very much for your comment. I have added it into my code. However, I have called the function r due to a suggestion by decorator-factory, and i get the error `main.py:15: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'r' was never awaited
  r()`. Do you have any ideas on why this is?

Comment: if you define `async` function then you need `await` to run it `await r()` - but problem is that you can't run `await r()` outside function. Maybe you should run this inside event `on_ready()`. But some examples use `bot.load_extension("cogs.maincog")` to load `cogs/maincog.py` and probably you would need `bot.load_extension("music")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define `async` function like `async def r()` then you would have to run it `await r()`. Problem is that you can't run `await` outside functions. You would have to run it in some `async` function - but it make the same problem with running this `async` function.

You may try to run it in event `on_ready()` which is `async` function.

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    for item in cogs:
        await item.setup(client)
```